How to address EdgeDB error of `constraints cannot contain paths with more than one hop`?
Here is a near minimal example from my .esdl file:
abstract type Base;
type A extending Base;
type B extending Base;
type C extending Base;
type D extending Base;

type Combo {
    obj1: Base;
    obj2: Base;

    # My goal is to support certain combinations of types but not others.
    # E.g., A <> A is not supported, but A <> B is supported, for sake of example.
    constraint expression on (
        not (.obj1 is A and .obj2 is A) or
        not (.obj1 is A and .obj2 is D) or
        not (.obj1 is B and .obj2 is C)
    );

    # This also produces the same error (just one of the numerous variations I've tried)
    # constraint expression on (
    #     not (__subject__.obj1 is typeof A and __subject__.obj2 is typeof A) or
    #     not (__subject__.obj1 is typeof A and __subject__.obj2 is typeof D) or
    #     not (__subject__.obj1 is typeof B and __subject__.obj2 is typeof C)
    # );
}

The error this produces is:
error: constraints cannot contain paths with more than one hop
    ┌─ /<path>/default.esdl:11:9
    │
11  │ ╭         constraint expression on (
12  │ │             not (.obj1 is A and .obj2 is A) or
13  │ │             not (.obj1 is A and .obj2 is D) or
14  │ │             not (.obj1 is B and .obj2 is C)
15  │ │         );
    │ ╰──────────^ error

There is this documentation, which states:

you can only reference single (non-multi) properties and links defined on the object type.

In this case, I am not using multi, so I don't think this would apply.
This feels like a fairly straightforward use case – is there something obvious I'm missing? Am I fundamentally modeling this in a way that I shouldn't be?
(Note: I'm using EdgeDB v5.6)
Thanks.
